# resize image and then upload using angular-js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one file control. I want to resize image(300x300) which is uploaded through this file control and then want to upload it to server for saving it in DB.

I have tried to install angular-images-resizer(https://github.com/FBerthelot/angular-images-resizer)  but it gives me error.

**Can anyone help me any script or dependency which would work in Angularjs 1.X.**

```
Cloning into '.'...
remote: Counting objects: 103, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (88/88), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (103/103), 1.03 MiB | 71.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 103 (delta 11), reused 80 (delta 10), pack-reused 0
Checking connectivity... done.
Note: checking out 'aebc495ac44e65db8fd39da1ff36a3fcf0e504ff'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

error: unable to create file docs/partials/api/images-resizer.service.readLocalPicService@readFileInput
Read file input and convert it into base64 file.html (Invalid argument)
error: unable to create file docs/partials/api/readLocalPicService.readFileInput
Read file input and convert it into base64 file.html (Invalid argument)
error: unable to create file docs/partials/api/readLocalPicService@readFileInput
Read file input and convert it into base64 file.html (Invalid argument)
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Comment: This demo show how to setup the Uploader as an angular directive. Image resizing is a feature natively provided by Fine Uploader as well: https://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/11/01/full-stack-javascript-image-uploader-using-angularjs-node-js/